# Compared with plain RSA , what is the advantage of randomised public key encryption scheme such as EIGamal encryption?

Tags: rsa, public-key

I am new to cryptography, I am very interested in cryptography, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hint: a name on the class roll is encrypted with plain RSA. You know the ciphertext and public key. That key's modulus is too large to factor. How do you nevertheless efficiently find which name was enciphered?